# Identification request: SOT-23-3 1F and lying 8 (infinity)

Tags: identification, surface-mount

What is the component in SOT23-3 with marking F1 and lying 8 or infinity mark, please?

This is a part of Semikron inverter board.
Pictures:
[image: SOT23-3-1F8]
[image: SOT23-3-1F8-2nd]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is a SOT23.

The point mark under the "1F" and the one digit orthogonal lot code is typical from ONSEMI. So it might be BC847BLT1G / BC847BLT3G.

https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/bc846alt1-d.pdf

Answer (score 3):

It is probably a BC847B NPN, 45 V, 100 mA NPN general-purpose transistor.

Made by various manufacturers including NXP, most using a 1F main marking, with various lot codes (the 8).